# How to extract the digital signature from a PDF with TCPDF?

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I need to extract the digital signature from the PDF on PHP, but I don't know how to do this. I've heard that tcpdf does this, but I didn't find how.

Comment: This https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_052/ ?

Comment: But in this example show just how to set signature in pdf. What I really want is how to get signature from pdf.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?